# Handlebars converts array of strings to array of variables

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js

My problem is that when i send data to handlebars template it converts my array of strings to array of variables:

```
res.render('index', { 
  title: 'Express' ,
  chartT:"title",
  lab:['test','test2','test3'],
  dat:[1,3,5]
});
```

Template code:

```
  <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    <script>
      var pollOptions = [{{{lab}}}];
      var pollData = [{{{dat}}}];
      createChart("mychart",pollOptions,pollData);
    </script>
```

And the problem that in pollOptions i got this

```
var pollOptions = [test,test2,test3];
```

Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined

I don't know why the template convert them...

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HandleBars` dedicated to HTML templating (Not to render a JS variable)
You can do something like this (Without handlebars):

```
var pollOptions = ["{{{lab}}}"];
var pollData = ["{{{dat}}}"];
```

Comment: I use handlebars for templating...e.g.:<h1>{{title}}</h1> passing down data from the server so it can show to the user, but i also need to supply data for the chart (the variables there to make the code more readable)

Comment: Yes, i know. What caused the caught error is that `handlebars` removes `'` from the variables which means `javascript` engine will consider them as javascript variable instead of `String` you're expecting.

Comment: Ok, but what is the solution , can i force down the strings or should i make an ajax call to the server ( to a different route) that will supply the data to the chart or register a helper or just get rid of the template engine and use some front-end framework or libraries?   The solution above doesn't work even with html.

Comment: unfortunately the updated solution doesn't work the result is: ["test,test,test"]

Comment: I ended up creating a new route(/api/getPools) and got the data with fetch, thank you for trying to help, i am going to accept your solutions for clarifying that i cannot send down strings

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have figured it out!

```
var rawData = "{{{lab}}}";
var pollData = rawData.split(",");
```

And now i can use it as a string array